# How to teach an NPC a word of power?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to teach my companion to use a Shout, but when i select him, and write the console command, the shout goes to me. I want he become like the Greybeards. How do i add the shout/word of power to an NPC and not on me?

Comment: As far as I could see, this command is specific to the player and can't be applied to NPC.

Comment: I am trying to figure that out too, kind of annoying. Bethesda should add it in the next patch, or someone should make a mod for it. Also, I wish you could do more than just walk around when you have used the console command "tc" (which switches your controls to that npc.

Answer (score 7):

NPCs can be taught words of power by using the console command `AddShout`. `TeachWord` takes the player only, but `AddShout` is available for any selected entity.

One word of warning, tho':

NPCs will always use the maximum power level of any shout they know and are using, and if you teach e.g. Fire Breath to a follower, you are likely to get caught in the crossfire, if you'll pardon the pun.

While NPCs will recognize and use shouts given to them by use of `AddShout`, they will pay no heed to wether or not you are in the way, so if you give a shout to a follower, be prepared to die. A lot.

Comment: @kotekzot: Because they are a year apart and represent radically different answers.

Comment: If you want to keep the old one around for old times' sake, just post it in a separate section below your original answer and specify it as 'original answer'.

Comment: @kotekzot: Actually, one of them mostly speaks to lore, and is *technically* correct.

Comment: @kotekzot: Well, the old answer is gone now, so that's that.

Comment: But...now I'm curious as to what the old answer said <:(

Comment: @Alex: It was a lore-oriented analysis as to why the question makes no sense.

Comment: You can always view old answers by clicking on the 'edited' date below the answer.  You can see a history of answer revisions from there.

Comment: Looks like lydia can finally take revenge for all the times you fus-ro-dah'ed her of a cliff.

Comment: " you are likely to get caught in the crossfire, if you'll pardon the pun." That mean if you give the shout to your follower and uses it, he/she will say watch it as if you shouted at her instead.